# what is the difference between __FILE__ and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']?

Tags: php

```
define('QA_BASE_DIR', dirname(empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? __FILE__ : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/');
```

what is the difference between `__FILE__` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` ?

Comment: `__FILE__` is the actual filename that contains the reference to `__FILE__` (which could be an included file); `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is the name of the script that the browser requested

Comment: They are absolutely identical.

Comment: @HassanAzimi:  the are absolutely NOT identical.  `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is the absolute path to the file of the request... before symbolic links have been followed.   `__FILE__` is the absolute path to file that contains `__FILE__` ... after symbolic links have been followed.    To check if the current file is the requested file:  `__FILE__ == realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP documentation, the difference is that `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` contains the absolute path to the current script, and in CLI mode, may contains a relative path.

`__FILE__`  will contains you the path of included file if used inside an included file, or the path of main file if used inside the main file.

Answer (score 1):

Blackquoting from http://www.qualitycodes.com/tip/17/difference-between-serverscriptfilename-and-file.html:

> `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` variable will return same path whether it is used in the main file or in an included file on the other hand `__FILE__` variable will return you the path of included file if used inside an included file and the path of main file if used inside the main file. I am referring to main file the one whose name is displayed in the address bar of browser.

Comment: also... `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is before symbolic links have been followed.   `__FILE__` is after symbolic links have been followed   ie, the `realpath()` function applied

Comment: Also `__FILE__` uses `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` while `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` uses `/`